# Worklight: An internal error occurred during: "Worklight application builder"

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

When i import project to eclipes i've this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Upgrade Worklight Projects".
No server host specified
```

[image]

When build project  i've this error :
[image]
Can anyone help me ?

Here is my eclipse verison:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screen shot, you are using Eclipse Indigo
Worklight 6.0 supports only: Eclipse Java EE for Developers **4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)** or Eclipse Classic 4.2.2.

Download Eclipse Java EE for Developers 4.2.2 ("Juno" SR2)
Install Worklight 6.0 on it.
Import your project

See if it then works.

Comment: But my project build in worklight version 5.0.6,how i can fix this ?

Comment: Install a separate Eclipse Juno 4.2.2. Export your project from Eclipse Indigo. Import your project to Eclipse Juno 4.2.2

Comment: But i don't want using eclipse juno because it can't using apache derby and my project version is 5.0.6 and i don't want using new version 6.0.How i can fix this ?

Comment: If you don't want to install Worklight 6.0, why did you install it...? or was this automatically updated to the latest Worklight version?

Comment: because i've change computer so,i've install eclipse again,in my old computer when i setup it is version 5.0.6 but now when i've new setup,it auto install version 6.0.How i can check what version of worklight i want install

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot. Worklight 5.0.6 is no longer publicly available. I suggest that you open a new question with the problems you are facing in 6.0 (you mentioned something about derby), maybe it is solvable).

Comment: Are you a Worklight customer? The version on the developerWorks web site is for non IBM customers and is provided for evaluation purposes. As an IBM Worklight customer you can get all versions.